# Slow string writes in Cassandra

Tags: python, database, cassandra

I'm running Cassandra 3.10 with Python 3.6 and Cassandra driver version 3.10. I have a simple table with two defined columns, an integer ID as the primary key and a text data column.

On my local machine writing a thousand rows of 4000-byte strings into this table using a prepared INSERT statement takes approximately half a second; but writing a thousand rows of 4100-byte string takes 45 seconds. The hundredfold decrease in performance happens somewhere around the 4050-byte mark. What is the cause of this and is there a way to combat it?

Comment: Have you tried any suggestions related to Cassandra optimizations? Examples: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/31827/what-to-do-for-performance-tuning-of-cassandra-dat.html https://github.com/seancxmao/documentation/wiki/cassandra-optimization

Comment: Between 4000 and 4100 is 4096 - I imagine we may be allocating a 4k chunk of memory somewhere in the internals, and if you cross that, we have to allocate another (or allocate on heap, which then leads to gc later).

Comment: BoboDarph: thanks for the link. Some of those optimizations are already in use but they don't really address this specific question.

Jeff: I figured 4k is some sort of a limit, however I'm stunned that crossing such a small limit leads to such drastic performance issues, especially since Cassandra is supposedly designed for large amounts of data and fast writes.